# How to extract characters from strings using a common preceding pattern?

Tags: r, regex, substring

I'm trying to use the sub function to isolate the Parcel Number from a messy string variable. The parcel numbers are identified within the string by a preceding "ParNum:" the characters around the desired number vary, but they follow the general form of these two examples.

```
string1 <- "Legal Description:  PrpId:0511552031 ParNum:0511552031 CC:05 T:7 R:8"
string2 <- "Legal Description:  Rmrk:PT OF PrpId:0511552031 ParNum:0511552031 CC:05 T:7 R:8"
```

Miserable Failed effort:

```
> sub("[^:]*:)*[^:]*:", "", string1)
[1] "0511552031 ParNum:0511552031 CC:05 T:7 R:8"
```

Desired result:

```
0511552031
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using the following pattern with `sub`:

```
.*ParNum:([^[:blank:]]*).*
```

This matches `ParNum:`, and then *captures* any non space/tab characters which follows `ParNum:`.  The captured number is then made available in the first capture group as `\\1`.

Code snippet:

```
string1 <- "Legal Description:  PrpId:0511552031 ParNum:0511552031 CC:05 T:7 R:8"
sub(".*ParNum:([^[:blank:]]*).*", "\\1", string1)
[1] "0511552031"
```

### Demo

Answer (score 1):

I find this easier to do with the `stringr` package from `tidyverse`. (In fact a question like this was what first prompted me to install `stringr`)

```
library(stringr)

string1 <- "Legal Description:  PrpId:0511552031 ParNum:0511552031 CC:05 T:7 R:8"
string2 <- "Legal Description:  Rmrk:PT OF PrpId:0511552031 ParNum:0511552031 CC:05 T:7 R:8"

str_extract(string1, "(?<=ParNum:)[^[:blank:]]*")
# [1] "0511552031"
```

Also, `str_extract` and `sub` are vectorized so the following works

```
strings <- c(string1, string2)
str_extract(strings, "(?<=ParNum:)[^[:blank:]]*")
# [1] "0511552031" "0511552031"
sub(".*ParNum:([^[:blank:]]*).*", "\\1", strings)
# [1] "0511552031" "0511552031"
```

The pattern `(?<=)` is regex for lookbehind. This [site](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) has more information about lookarounds.